# Getting ink! contract metadata from the chain

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I am playing around with `ink!` and invoking contract pallets. After uploading the contract to the chain from the polkadot extension, I get a JSON file back describing the metadata for the contract, especially the method calls and arguments.

This would presume that I need to externally manage the metadata for the contract.

Is there no way to get this from the chain directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata is not stored on chain to avoid bloat. Only the compiled wasm is uploaded to the chain. This is the same way it works on Ethereum [with compiled solidity being stored on-chain](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/what-is-an-abi-of-a-smart-contract-examples-and-usage). As pointed out in the article, you can generate the ABI if you have the contract source.

Therefore, if you have the `ink!` contract sources you can generate the `ABI` using `cargo-contract build ...`. In future, [it may also be possible using the crate `contract-metadata`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1229).